# How does grpc-python maxworker work when handling request

Tags: grpc-python

I was wondered that how does python grpc maxworker work. If I set maxworker 10

```
grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=int)
```

Does it mean if I send 15 req to the grpc server, it will only handle 10 req at the same time(if my cpu num support this amount of concurrency). The other 5 req will hang on until the first btach with 10 req finish handling.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes

Long answer:

1. The request will hang on if current requests reach to max_workers
2. If you do not set max_workers, it depends on your CPU but no more than 32 since Python 3.8
3. You can still set a large number greater than your CPU limit.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor